# How to sequentially iterate through object values of a Map in Flutter and to return each value one by one as you iterate?

Tags: flutter

```
  Map<String, VideoPlayerController> controllers = {
    'one${1 + 1}': VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/6.mp4'),
    'one${1 + 2}': VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/2.mp4'),
    'one${1 + 3}': VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/3.mp4'),
    'one${1 + 4}': VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/4.mp4'),
    'one${1 + 6}': VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/1.mp4'),
    'one${1 + 7}': VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/7.mp4'),
    'one${1 + 8}': VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/8.mp4'),
  };

  controllerLooper3() {
    for (value in controllers.values) {
      return value;
    }
  }
```

I am trying to iterate and return each value of the Map/to access each value sequentially. However, when I try to loop and return the value I am only getting the first value of the object. How do I do it so that it loops through the the value data but without changing that data into a string type.That is each objects value is maintained without changing its raw make up. That is I do not want to print it I just want a mechanism that is accessing the values sequentially one by one and returning each value one by one as it iterates.

Comment: Why map, why not list?

Comment: What is the purpose? Why don't you just return the whole map?

Comment: You can check my answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887282/video-player-multiple-back-to-back-videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is a demo using the [video player plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player). Instead of a `Map`, per Remi's recommendation in the comments to your question above, I created a basic video model with title and controller properties and added them to a `List`. It's much easier to use a `List` (with proper models) if you're looking to make a YouTube-like feed (most likely using a `ListView` or `CustomScrollView`). Ensure your `pubspec.yaml` is updated with your video assets (and change the below filenames), and the example should work for you. The listeners below will print when the video is initialized and the duration.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Video Player Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Video Player Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<VideoModel> _controllers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controllers = [
      VideoModel(
          title: 'Alpha',
          controller: VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/small.mp4')),
      VideoModel(
          title: 'Beta',
          controller: VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/small.mp4')),
      VideoModel(
          title: 'Gamma',
          controller: VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/small.mp4')),
    ];
    _controllerLooper();
  }

  _controllerLooper() {
    for (VideoModel video in _controllers) {
      final listener = () {
        if (video.controller.value.initialized) {
          print('${video.title} - video initialized');
        }
        print('${video.title} duration: ${video.controller.value.position}');
      };
      video.controller
        ..addListener(listener)
        ..setVolume(1.0)
        ..setLooping(true)
        ..initialize();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _controllers.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final controller = _controllers[index].controller;
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                if (controller.value.isPlaying) {
                  controller.pause();
                } else if (!controller.value.isPlaying) {
                  controller.play();
                }
              },
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 16.0 / 9.0,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controllers[index].controller),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class VideoModel {
  VideoModel({this.title, this.controller});

  final String title;
  final VideoPlayerController controller;
}
```

Comment: haven't yet tried your code doing some assignment but I am trying to make a news feed of videos.

Comment: as in I want to use controllerLooper3() as an iterator then tie it to event listener that plays and pauses different videos displayed as a feed. You know like YouTube... I am really stuck....

Comment: I am putting your 'for loop' in controllerLooper3 method so that I tack on addListener method to listen for play and pause events. However the addListener method is throwing an error that 'addListener' was called on null. Receiver: null.  I have tried your code what can I do?

Comment: @K.chim I changed my answer after looking at the `video_player` plugin, which I think you're using. Hopefully the above helps.

Comment: Works like Charm!! you are Genius!! Now how do I control the play and pause? Everything is playing simultaneously at once

Comment: @K.chim I updated the code to add a `GestureDetector` to each video cell that will play/pause the video depending on the current state.

Comment: your wonderful. Appreciate it. Should I have any more problems as I develop the App I'll get back to you through this post. Cheers

Comment: wanted to know how would we implement thumbnails on the videos? you know like an image cover from a frame of the videos and displayed as an image then when you tap it starts playing the video. Like YouTube does. I tried using the thumbnails plugin but the documentation is ill explained.