# Flutter - Streaming and Caching videos

Tags: caching, flutter, video-streaming

I'm developing an application in flutter which is showing videos in a list (like Instagram). Videos must be streamed so I can't download them first and then play them.

I want to cache them while they are being streamed. I've seen `CacheManager` class but it will download the whole file and then pass it to video player to play it.

How can I implement a cache manager to show the video file while it is being downloaded to cache folder?

Comment: Have you tried https://pub.dev/packages/video_player?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887282/how-to-play-videos-sequentialy-on-video-player-plugin

Answer (score 21):

I might be writing this a bit late but just in case anybody looking for a solution soon.
By the moment the official video_player plugin doesn't support video caching over network yet.

But fortunately, there been some attempts by contributors to add caching feature to the video_player plugin
You can track updates and find another PRs here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28094

Replace video_player in your pubspec.yaml with

```
  video_player:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/sanekyy/plugins.git
      ref: caching
      path: packages/video_player/video_player
```

In case of you are using chewie or other libraries that depend on video_player plugin add:

```
dependency_overrides:
  video_player:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/sanekyy/plugins.git
      ref: caching
      path: packages/video_player/video_player
```

And now to cache the video pass `useCache : true` to

```
_videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(videoURL, useCache: true);
```

By default both maxFileSize and maxCacheSize is set to 10 * 1024 * 1024 bytes.
To adjust the cache size:

```
  VideoPlayerController.setCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024, 200 * 1024 * 1024);
```

---

**Another Solution:**
Is to stream the video normally using the official plugin and to cache the video file using [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) simultaneously.

But this will lead to fetch the video twice the first time (Once for streaming through the video_player, Another for downloading the video through the cachemanager)

Here how the scenario would goes:

1- Check with flutter_cache_manager if the video_url is already downloaded and cached.

2- if the video is cached, pass the file path to video_player `VideoPlayerController.file(path)`, if not download the file using cachemanager and stream the video using `VideoPlayerController.network(videoURL)` (at this moment video is being fetched twice... by videoplayer and cachemanager).

Comment: Thank you, however when I use the `dependency_overrides ` method I get `Because flutter_video_caching_test depends on dependency_overrides from unknown source "video_player", version solving failed.` Any Idea?

Comment: It will cache the video after we initialize Video Controller. What if I want to cache the next 4-5 videos from my list for the first 5 seconds only.

Comment: @PratikButani did you get your answer to cache the next 4-5 videos? I need to implement the same thing.

Comment: I got this error message `The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.8.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.` 
Does this cached video player still work today??

Answer (score 2):

Visit https://github.com/elgsylvain85/cachedflickvideoplayer.git

It is a video player for flutter. It combines both: The flick_video_player plugin for the base architecture, own set of UI and The cached_video_player plugin for cache supporting.

In your pubspec.yaml file :

```
cachedflickvideoplayer:
git:
  url: https://github.com/elgsylvain85/cachedflickvideoplayer.git
```

a demo of code :

```
import 'package:cached_video_player/cached_video_player.dart';
import 'package:cachedflickvideoplayer/cachedflickvideoplayer.dart';
import 'package:cachedflickvideoplayer/controls/flick_landscape_controls.dart';
import 'package:cachedflickvideoplayer/controls/flick_video_with_controls.dart';
import 'package:cachedflickvideoplayer/manager/flick_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';


class ViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
 FlickManager flickManager;

  ViewPage() {
    flickManager = initVideo();
  }

  @override
  _ViewPageState createState() => _ViewPageState();

  FlickManager initVideo() {
    return FlickManager(
        cachedVideoPlayerController:
            CachedVideoPlayerController.network('https://media.istockphoto.com/videos/blurred-motion-of-people-in-restaurant-blur-background-video-id1190840021'),
        );
  }
}

class _ViewPageState extends State<ViewPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 100),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        height: 300,
                        child: FlickVideoPlayer(
                          flickManager: widget.flickManager,
                          flickVideoWithControlsFullscreen:
                              FlickVideoWithControls(
                            videoFit: BoxFit.contain,
                            controls: FlickLandscapeControls(),
                          ),
                        )),,
                  ]),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    widget.flickManager.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here ? else it will be considred as spam

Comment: Hi, Yes I've seen it but it's too green to can be accepted as a solution since it's a little bit buggy and cannot be customized enough... Thanks for the suggestion tho

Answer (score 1):

You can mix video_player with flutter_cache_manager.

```
/// Get a file from the cache or download and insert it into the memory.
final url = 'link-to-the-file';
final file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url, key: url);
_videoController = VideoPlayerController.file(file)
  ..initialize().then(
    (_) => initialize(),
  );
```

As the result, if the manager does not find a file in the cache by url, it will download it, insert it into the memory and return the file object.

This solution is only effective if you work with small sizes video.

Comment: but this means that the video only then starts playing once the video has been completed downloaded before starting to play it (which can depending on the video size can take quite some time)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's only effective if you have small sizes video.

Comment: this approach should be taken with streaming returning data should be appending in caching as well as feeding to renderer.

Answer (score 1):

All one solution is to Use https://pub.dev/packages/better_player_plus.
because in the production application, I am using https://pub.dev/packages/better_player_plus I make a reel view after loading the network video turn off the internet and again go to an application where the video is played. but after one year I want to update some dependency then I find  better_player_plus.
better_player_plus package provides advanced functionality.
Functionality
Video caching
Events
advance level video play UI
streaming (Suport m3u8)
updated dependency

```
dependencies:
  better_player_plus: ^1.0.5
```

Comment: Are you in any way affiliated with better_player_plus?