# is there a way to play a multimedia file saved in ram memory?

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for a way to play a multimedia file saved in the ram memory of the mobile phone in flutter !.
Apparently the video_player package does not accept files in memory but only files on ssd, asset or url. Do you know a way to do this in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to cache videos?

If yes, you could try using [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) to cache your videos and play them from the cache.

Do note that, as written in the package README:

> By default the cached files are stored in the temporary directory of the app. This means the OS can delete the files any time.

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61883216/11149234) from a similar thread on stack overflow.

**EDIT**

Since it is required to not save the video on it could be an option to use the [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player), which has the option to read a video file directly from memory, using `BetterPlayerDataSource.memory` as the data source.

Refer to [this section of the documentation](https://jhomlala.github.io/betterplayer/#/datasourceconfiguration) for more info.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i really don't want to store them in the ssd memory of the device.

Comment: @MaurizioMancini I see, what about the [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) package? It should have the BetterPlayerDataSourceType.MEMORY source type so you can pass it the video in bytes.