# Video player with cache issue using git link

Tags: git, flutter, caching, video-player, flutter-video-player

I am using video player with git link to download externally in my flutter project and i did this:

```yaml
video_player:
            git:
              url: ssh://github.com/sanekyy/plugins.git
              ref: caching
              path: packages/video_player/video_player
```

I have tried https on ssh place, but still not working and I am getting this error in my terminal.

for ssh:

```bash
stderr: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

for https:

```bash
Git error. Command: `git fetch`
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 20.207.73.82]: errno=Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: an SSH URL would be

```
ssh://git@github.com/sanekyy/plugins.git
      ^^^
```

You can check first if the network allows you to contact github.com through SSH or HTTPS with:

```bash
curl -v telnet://github.com:22
curl -v telnet://github.com:443
```

If both fail, you might need to check with your server, or your IT admin, why the route is blocked (firewall, network policy, ...)

Example of [HTTPS configuration here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61883216/6309).

Comment: well you are right but still its not working

Comment: @umairbinali What does the curl commands return?