# Video_player network video retrieve too slow

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

How to reduce delay before initialization network video in flutter video_player? It takes so much time to initialize, about 7 seconds. How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play videos sequentialy on video\_player without delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887282/how-to-play-videos-sequentialy-on-video-player-without-delay)

Comment: Probably not 

Comment: For example: app has 20 videos in a page view builder widget, but would will happens when user want to go to 8th video by fast swiping? Video controller tries to initialize again, it may take about 10 seconds, and it is doesn’t matter how many controllers we try to initialize, it takes delay in the end.